# Replace host for ip on a .txt file

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing

I have about 14,800 files scattered on a folder called `/actlogs/` and subfolders. These files contain in the first line a link like:

```
http://server.com/file.pdf
```

I need to replace the string "server.com" to the actual IP address of "server.com"

Any way to find *.log on /actlogs/ and subfolders and for each file replace the host for their IP?

I'm working on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `sed`:

```
sed 's/server\.com/192.168.0.1/' *.log
```

`sed` is a Stream EDitor which processes the input line by line. Here we are using `s`, the substitute command `s/regex/replacement/flags`. Once you have checked that this is what you want, you can add the `i` flag which will make the changes "in place." The `*` will glob in the shell and pass all files that end in `.log` to sed as input.

```
sed 's/server\.com/192.168.0.1/' *.log
```

Note that this will replace only the first occurrence of the pattern on each line. If you want to replace all the occurrences regardless of where they appear you can use the global flag:

```
sed 's/server\.com/192.168.0.1/g' *.log
```

For a hierarchy of directories that you need to search you can use `find` and then execute `sed` on the results:

```
find /home/www/ -type f -name '*.log' -exec \
    sed 's/server\.com/192.168.0.1/g' {} +
```

Comment: works great on first level, but is not searching on all subfolder, I have 3 more levels, for example, /log/2019/june/one.log i have logs on /log/ and on /log//2019/ and on /log/2019/june/ any way to do it recursive in all files on log folder?

Comment: @ubunthor you should be able to use find to locate the files and then run sed on each one that you find. Again try it without the `-i` flag first to make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job:

```
find . -type f -name "*.log" -exec sed 's/server\.com/192.168.0.1/g' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @user1774469 correct answer, to allow replacing the string in `*.log` files in all subfolders under log, with bash, is achieveable with

1) Activate `globstar` shell option:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

2) Issue @user1774469 correct command with the following modification

```
sed 's/server\.com/192.168.0.1/' /actlogs/**/*.log
```

Then it will match all files with `.log` extension anywhere below the `/actlogs/` directory.